# UnboundLocalError when trying to use decorator function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I've been trying to use Python's decorator functions to make a completely stupid project, but I've been getting this error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mana_cost' referenced before assignment
```

and I'm not really sure what's wrong. Here's the code so far (not even sure if it's functional yet, WIP obvs):

```
from stuff.mana_pool import ManaPool

def spell(mana_cost):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print(mana_cost)
            mana_pool = kwargs['mana_pool']
            cost = {}
            for mana_type in ['W', 'U', 'B', 'R', 'G']:
                cost[mana_type] = mana_cost.count(mana_type)
                mana_cost = mana_cost.replace(mana_type, '')
            cost['generic'] = int(mana_cost)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorator

my_pool = ManaPool()

@spell("2BB")
def func(thingy):
    print(thingy)

func('boop', mana_pool=my_pool)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to define `mana_cost` before you pass it into the function

Comment: You reassigned `mana_cost` inside `wrap`. That means `wrap` doesn't see the closure variable. Don't try to reassign the name.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, I see it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @linky00 I am facing the same issues, can you share how you solved this issue?